# ApiAxle: Modifying timeout parameter if backend server is slow to respond

Tags: timeout, apiaxle

I am following the instructions at: and am getting the error: http://apiaxle.com/docs/try-it-now/

```
{"meta":{"version":1,"status_code":504},
"results":{"error":{"type":"EndpointTimeoutError",
"message":"API endpoint timed out."}}}
```

I'm searching on google but have not yet found how to set a larger timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation at http://apiaxle.com/api.html, I took a shot and came up with the following:

```
axle> api "apiname" create endPoint="server.org:port" endPointTimeout=30
```

Response was:

```
{ protocol: 'http',
  tokenSkewProtectionCount: 3,
  apiFormat: 'json',
  endPointTimeout: 30,
  disabled: false,
  strictSSL: true,
  sendThroughApiKey: false,
  sendThroughApiSig: false,
  hasCapturePaths: false,
  allowKeylessUse: false,
  keylessQps: 2,
  keylessQpd: 172800,
  endPoint: 'server.org:port',
  createdAt: 1400333254388 }

axle> api apiname linkkey "1234"
```

Response was:

```
 { qpd: 172800, qps: 2, disabled: false, createdAt: 1400331617778 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify an existing api :

`api "apiname" update endPointTimeout=10`